# The Ribbon Pages for an Outlook Appointment Replacement Form Region are disabled

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ribbon

Using C# and VSTO 2015 to create an Outlook Add-in with a custom Calendar and a replacement form region for Appointments

All works fine - except the form Ribbon:

When a user adds a New Appointment (or opens an existing Appointment) in the custom Calendar - my form region opens with the same Ribbon as the usual Outlook Appointment

However, apart from the Appointment Page, almost all the ribbon items on other Pages are disabled.
How do I enable these items?

Answer (score 0):

Had a thought and tested it

It is simple really - a Replacement Forms cannot use most Outlook Ribbon Items!

In Visual Studio 2015 "Add New Item" the wizard for an Outlook From Region actually graphically shows this

I guess at least one of the reasons is that the Form Region has no control for the Outlook appointment "Body" - and so nowhere to show the Attachments (or to perform the  FORMAT TEXT Tab options etc.)